# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react app that I'm trying to start locally with `npm start`. The page that loads is completely blank and the console gives the following message:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See `url` for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    React 2
    useTheme useTheme.js:4
    ThemeProvider ThemeProvider.js:34
    React 17
    tsx index.tsx:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3
        __webpack_require__
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
react.development.js:1465
    React 2
    useTheme useTheme.js:4
    ThemeProvider ThemeProvider.js:34
    React 17
    tsx index.tsx:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3
```

I'm very new to React so I'm not sure how to go about solving this. I suspect that error 3 is to blame (multiple copies of React), but I'm not sure. This app has been running in production for the better part of 2 years, and still is, with absolutely no changes so I'm finding it hard to believe that there is a version problem (point 1) or incorrect usage of hooks (point 2) as that would cause it to not work in production either, right? It's only locally that it's failing. So that leaves the possibility that I have more than one copy of React, and I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
{
  "name": "my-app-react-pwa",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.22.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.19",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "store2": "^2.13.1",
    "swr": "^1.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is the output of `npm ls react`:

```
  +-- @material-ui/core@4.12.3
  | +-- @material-ui/styles@4.11.4
  | | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | +-- @material-ui/system@4.12.1
  | | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | +-- @material-ui/utils@4.11.2
  | | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | +-- react-dom@16.14.0
  | | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | +-- react-transition-group@4.4.2
  | | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | `-- react@16.14.0
  +-- @material-ui/icons@4.11.2
  | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  +-- @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.60
  | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  +-- @testing-library/react@12.1.3
  | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  +-- material-table@1.69.3
  | +-- @material-ui/pickers@3.2.2
  | | +-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | | `-- rifm@0.7.0
  | |   `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | +-- react-beautiful-dnd@13.0.0
  | | +-- react-redux@7.2.6
  | | | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | | +-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | | `-- use-memo-one@1.1.2
  | |   `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | +-- react-double-scrollbar@0.0.15
  | | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  +-- react-dom@17.0.2
  | `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
  +-- react-router-dom@6.2.1
  | +-- react-router@6.2.1
  | | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  | `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
  +-- react-scripts@5.0.0
  | `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
  +-- react@17.0.2
  `-- swr@1.2.2
    `-- react@16.14.0 deduped
```

And `index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <App />
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The app only has a single page/URL, here is the `App.tsx`:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { SWRConfig } from "swr";
import AzureAdAuthenticator from "./components/AzureAdAuthenticator";
import Tables from "./components/Tables";
import config from "./config";
import theme from "./theme";

function createDataFetcher(
  adAuthenticatedFetch: (path: string, options: any) => Promise<Response>
) {
  return async (path: string, paramOptions: any) => {
    const contentTypeHeader = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };
    paramOptions = paramOptions ? paramOptions : { headers: {} };

    if (paramOptions.body) {
      paramOptions.body = JSON.stringify(paramOptions.body);
    }

    var options = {
      ...paramOptions,
      headers: {
        ...paramOptions.headers,
        ...contentTypeHeader,
      },
    };

    return adAuthenticatedFetch(config.API_HOST + path, options).then((r) =>
      r.json()
    );
  };
}

export const AooContext = createContext({
  dataFetcher: createDataFetcher(fetch),
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AzureAdAuthenticator
        render={(
          adAuthenticatedFetch: (
            path: string,
            options: any
          ) => Promise<Response>
        ) => (
          <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
              alvtimeFetcher: createDataFetcher(adAuthenticatedFetch),
            }}
          >
            <SWRConfig
              value={{
                fetcher: createDataFetcher(adAuthenticatedFetch),
                revalidateOnFocus: false,
              }}
            >
              <Tables />
            </SWRConfig>
          </AppContext.Provider>
        )}
      ></AzureAdAuthenticator>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Which loads the `Tables.tsx` component:

```
import { Options } from "material-table";
import React from "react";
import { mutate } from "swr";
import CustomerTable from "./CustomerTable";
import UserTable from "./UserTable";

export const setCache = (path: string, data: any) => mutate(path, data, false);

export const globalTableOptions: Options<object> = {
  addRowPosition: "first",
};

export default function Tables() {
  return (
    <>
      <UserTable />
      <CustomerTable />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: post ` index.tsx`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka added to post

Comment: post the component this error throws

Comment: @PalBo Not sure if that's your problem but you have a typo in `App.tsx`, you named your context `AooContext` while you are trying to use `AppContext`.